# Submit TextBox From Within A Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to do something simple.  I have a text box in a repeater Item that will allow people to add a note to the item.  My code is not working, it doesn't seem like anything is happening at all.

ASPX:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>

                            <ItemTemplate>

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="NoteTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="SubmitNote" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="lnkClient_Click" CommandName="AddNote" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UID")%>'/>                                       


    <asp:Label ID="ShowNotes" runat="server" Text='<%# getNotes(Eval("UID").ToString())%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CODEBEHIND - This is what should be executed on click.  I replaced my SQL code with Response.Write:

```
public void lnkClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)(sender);
        string FID = btn.CommandArgument.ToString();            
        string note = ((TextBox)rptList.Items[0].FindControl("NoteTextBox")).Text;
        Response.Write(FID + " " + note);

    }
```

UPDATE: Changed some settings and now the only problem I am having is that the text entered client side is not passed to the command.

Comment: The event is not firing on click.  It doesn't reach my breakpoints.

Comment: use itemcommand event of repeater...it should work...

Comment: I'll try that.  I got to fire by turning setting 'validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false"' but it is giving me null values.

Comment: Where do I wire up the ItemCommand? Also, I have about 10 different buttons in each repeater so I need to make sure ItemCommand doesn't fire on all of them, or if it does it can separate which button was clicked.

Comment: remove onclick event of that button and use the code which i have posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 protected void Repeater_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNote"))
            {       
            string FID =e.CommandArgument.ToString();    
            TextBox txtNote=e.Item.FindControl("NoteTextBox") as TextBox;    
            string note=txtNote.Text; 
            Response.Write(FID + " " + note);
            }
    }
```

and in Mark up

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater_OnItemCommand" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
```

Comment: Now nothing is firing again when I made those changes.  My only issue had become that the text box wasn't passing any values. I edited as you posted but now when I click submit nothing happens.  I changed the Button to this `<asp:Button ID="SubmitNote" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandName="AddNote" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UID") %>'/>   `  I set a breakpoint at the if line and it is never reached when I click submit.

Comment: Removed and moved my data binding to !postback and is working.  However, the repeater_OnItemCommand still does not fire unless I manually set it to fire onclick.

Comment: repeater_OnItemCommand works....don't know why it is not working at your end..anyways..your code worked...that's more important !!